# Mount a volume in docker-compose. How is it done?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

If I execute this cmd in a console:

```
 docker run -it --rm --link rabbit --link elasticsearch -v "$PWD"/logstash:/config-dir logstash logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
```

It runs fine. Inside ./logstash folder there is a logstash.conf.
But now I'm trying to put in a docker-compose and the same doesn't works:

```
  logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  links:
    - "elasticsearch:elasticsearch"
    - "rabbit:rabbit"
  volumes:
      - $PWD/logstash:/config_dir
  command:
    - "-f /config_dir/logstash.conf"
```

But I cannot see the difference between both commands. Some help? How is it volume mounting done? Or is the command that doesn't works? Response from logstash init is:

```
logstash_1        | {:timestamp=>"2016-07-06T15:43:06.663000+0000", :message=>"No config files found: / /config_dir/logstash.conf\nCan you make sure this path is a logstash config file?", :level=>:error}
rabbitmq_logstash_1 exited with code 1
```

**Edit:** I finally solved the problem by removing the command and using the default command of the original image, but I still don't understand the problem and how the same command is passed to docker and works but if it is passed throught docker-compose don't.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 41):

Your config is probably not working because your version of docker-compose does not execute shell expansions while creating your container. That means that docker compose is trying to find a literal path `$PWD/logstash` instead of expanding `$PWD` to your present directory. Later versions of docker compose do allow for environment variable expansion.

Docker-compose [does allow relative paths](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) though, through the use of `./`, which references the ***folder the compose file is in, not necessarily your `pwd`,*** so you just need to change your compose file to be:

```
volumes:
    - ./logstash:/config_dir
```

Comment: No way :( The same error. I suspect of the command because the error message puts another slash "No config files found: / /config_dir/logstash.conf. What is this first slash for?

Comment: `./dir` is how you reference a directory on your `pwd` if you did `.dir` it would look for a dir name ".dir"

Comment: silly question, but is the logstash folder in the same directory as your docker compose file?

Comment: You could also just use an absolute path, if that works then you know that the problem is your relative path

Comment: Update - Environment variable expansion is actually supported in Docker Compose files version 2 and 3. Still, the relative path syntax remains the preferable way to define volumes locations, since they are relative to the location of the compose file, rather than the user's current working directory.