# bash: cd: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, function, alias, ls

I'm writing a bash function to jump into my last editted folder.
In my example, the last edited folder is titled 'daniel'.

The bash function looks fine.

```
>>:~$ echo $(ls -d -1dt -- */ | head -n 1)
daniel/
```

And I can manually cd into the directory.

```
>>:~$ cd daniel
>>:~/daniel$
```

But I can't use the bash function to cd into the directory.

```
>>:~$ cd $(ls -d -1dt -- */ | head -n 1)
bash: cd: daniel/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That should work. There's some small detail you're overlooking that's not in the question.

Comment: What does `alias ls` say? Can you try it again with `/bin/ls` to ensure that it doesn't add any weird flags?

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you! Turns out someone added `alias ls= ls --color` in the bashrc of this server. My function works once I removed the alias.

Comment: May i ask why you use the -d switch twice?

Comment: @grail That is an error on my part,  `ls -1dt *` is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out someone added `alias ls=ls --color` to the bashrc of this server. My function works once the alias was removed. – Daniel Tan

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually thrown when you enter a path that does not exist. See [-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146123/bash-cd-desktop-no-such-file-or-directory).

But the $(ls -d -1dt -- */ | head -n 1) is not wrong in the output. Thus the reason must be the different usage of sh and bash in that moment.

In my case, I had a docker container with that error when I accessed the folder with bash. The container was broken since I had force-closed it after `docker-compose up` which did not work. After that, on the existing containers, I could only use sh, not bash. I found this because of [OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/963#issuecomment-605837291). I guess that bash is loaded later than sh, and that at an early error at the start of the container, only sh gets loaded.

That would fit since you are in the sh, which can be seen from >>. Using sh, everything will work as expected. But the expression gets solved by bash. Which is probably not loaded for whatever reason.

---

In docker, using docker-compose, I also had a similar error saying `sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /root/MYPROJECT`. That could be solved by mounting the needed volumes in the services using

```
services:
  host:
    volumes:
      - ~/MYPROJECT:/MYPROJECT # ~/path/on/host:/path/on/container
```

See [Mount a volume in docker-compose. How is it done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228386/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-how-is-it-done) and [How to mount a host directory with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157161/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-with-docker-compose?noredirect=1&lq=1) or the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).