# How to mount a host directory with docker-compose, with the "~/path/on/host" to be specified when running the host, not in the docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm wondering how you can mount a host directory using docker-compose.

At the moment I'm just using a regular Dockerfile and it's working fine. When I run the container I just specify the path on my host and the path on the container.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v ~/path/on/host:/path/on/container my-container
```

I'd like to to achieve this using docker-compose but I'm not sure how this works.My docker compose is below.

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
```

In addition, I need the ~/path/on/host to be specified when running the host, not in the docker-compose file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount a volume in docker-compose. How is it done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228386/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-how-is-it-done)

Comment: @leopal It differs in the question for `~/path/on/host` to be specified when running the host, not in the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/path/on/host:/path/on/container
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Then you can start your service with `docker-compose up -d`. Make sure to stop and remove first the container you started using docker commands otherwise you will get conflicts.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

Create a .env file with the contents:

```
HOST_PATH=~/path/on/host
```

and change your docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_PATH}:/path/on/container
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: I want the `~/path/on/host` to be specified when running the host, not in the docker-compose file

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "when running the host" but I updated the solution with a setting that comes from a variable set on host.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The directory is always empty.