# Docker does not sync folders from host to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried numerous different combinations on the docker-compose.yml file.

when this line :

```
- .:/var/www/html
```

changed to this :

```
- *:/var/www/html
```

Then it will copy over the files in the working directory but there is no sync.
Ive tried surrounding the line with qoutes, changing the dot to ./ but no results. var/www/html is either empty or has files in it only when using * but no sync happens.

Here are my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.0-apache

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite headers

COPY . /var/www/html/

COPY ./config/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    app:
        ports:
            - 80:80
        environment:
            - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/app/public
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
```

EDIT : 
Update. I tried removing the copy line, only worked so as to create an empty html dir on the container.
As far as how i check, I do docker exec -it on the runnint container and just do an ls command on the html dir.
I have thus far reinstalled docker toolbox and noticed there is a gui with it... I did not see any volumes when doing docker volume ls but the volume is shown in Kitematic.
However, the dir on the host machine is NOT what one would expect, it is not the folder on drive d that docker-compose is in, but instead a folder in my documents. Trying to change it to the correct one on the gui and it says invalid dir. I remember reading somewhere that docker has limited access to the host filesystem and i am wondering if I have not missed a step here and should instead share the entire drive D with docker.

EDIT 2 :
Added the folder on drive d to the vm named default into shared folders list, restarted all and still no dice. How can i specify a location on drive d?

Comment: how do you check if there are files in `/var/www/html`?

Comment: try following the examples from here : 
https://devopsheaven.com/docker/docker-compose/volumes/2018/01/16/volumes-in-docker-compose.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your folder sync between host and container, then you'll need to `mount` it instead of `copying` it:
[check this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

For your problem, you need to remove `COPY . /var/www/html/`  from Dockerfile

You could also check this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228386/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-how-is-it-done/38228877)

Comment: But how do i do that in the docker-compose file?

Comment: Accepting yours because it did got me thinking on the right track as to what i did wrong!

Comment: So what exactly did you do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So i got it fixed...
The solution for anyone else with the same problem, share out your D drive, then restart the docker machine and then write full path eg for drive D that has a Machine Folder name in Virtualbox as D_DRIVE.
/D_DRIVE/path/to/desired/folder

Thank you all for ideas. Rookie mistake this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the solution, please?