# Log file isn't created when use a docker container

Tags: c#, docker

I have a web api project I setup the log file to be created in the current directory with the name logs.txt (the configuration is inside the appsettings.json).
I run the web api using a docker container the api works (I can make calls) but doesn't create a log file.
The docker file was created by visual studio
This is the docker compose. How do I tell docker to create the log file?

```
version: '2.0'

networks:
  web-net:
    name: web-net
 
services:
  web-database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: web-database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: web
      POSTGRES_USER: web
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: web
    networks:
      - web-net 
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
   
  web-api:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
    container_name: web-api
    networks:
      - web-net
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web-database
```

Comment: Perhaps there's a misunderstanding of Docker here, but it's kind of like a virtual machine for whatever you're running. The log file is probably being created, but within the Docker container. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228386/mount-a-volume-in-docker-compose-how-is-it-done) will help you.

Comment: Are you checking inside the running container for the log file?

Comment: You should save the logs in volume so that they are available after the work is finished or the container is failed. See [Docker Volumes And Logging](https://medium.com/interleap/docker-volumes-and-logging-a839011950f7)

Comment: I dont know what change but the Iog file appears in the docker container which is good :). Now I want do access the file outside the docker container for that I going to have to map a local directory to the docker container. I going to check your link @AlexanderPetrov.

Comment: If I have my log directory  like this "path": ".\\Logs\\logs.txt", the file isn't created in the docker container but If I have like this "path": ".\\logs.txt" the file is created.  Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: You might find it easier to send the logs to stdout and not a file, so that then `docker logs` can review them.

Comment: The error was so stupid! Just change the the "\\" to this "/" in the volume mapping. Thanks for all help